# How to get to Angel Falls?

Tags: transportation, vantage-points, venezuela

I've been told that it's really difficult to get to the falls themselves.  [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Angel_Falls) seems to indicate you can only fly in.  What options exist for getting to a great view of the falls themselves?

Comment: I do not know but now I want to!

Comment: I've heard that there are tour guides that will hike you in, but it isn't for the weak willed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research and collected various answers:

From [about.com](http://gosouthamerica.about.com/cs/southamerica/a/VenAngelCanaima.htm) there are two possibilities:

> **Air:** As stated, access to Canaima National Park is by air to the
>   village of Canaima, about 50 km away from the falls. From there, you
>   take either a smaller plane and fly to an airstrip at Canaima Lagoon,
>   or travel by river to the lagoon. From the lagoon, you hike to a view
>   point of the falls.
>
> There are also daily flights via Puerto Ordaz connecting Canaima
>   airstrip with the major cities of Venezuela. The airstrip is a short
>   jeep-train ride from nearby Lodges. Check flights from your area to
>   Caracas or other Venezuelan cities with connections to Ciudad Bolicar
>   and Canaima. From this page, you can also browse hotels, rental cars,
>   and special deals.
>
> **Water:** From Canaima, when the water is neither too high or too low,
>   you can travel by motorized canoe, called curiara up the Carrao River,
>   then the Churun river to an point where you can then hike through the
>   jungle to the falls. The river portion takes about four hours, and you
>   should allow an hour or more for the hike. Canoe access to Angel Falls
>   is restricted to the rainy season, June to November.

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Falls)

> Angel Falls is one of Venezuela's top tourist attractions, though a
>   trip to the falls is a complicated affair. The falls are located in an
>   isolated jungle, and a flight from Puerto Ordaz or Ciudad Bolívar is
>   required to reach Canaima camp, the starting point for river trips to
>   the base of the falls. River trips generally take place from June to
>   December, when the rivers are deep enough for the wooden curiaras used
>   by the Pemon guides. During the dry season (December to March) there
>   is less water seen than in the other months.

Very interesting information can be found on [Backpacker-Tours](http://www.venezuela-tours.de/en/angel_falls.htm). They do not only explain how to get there but also mention a price and duration. Similar information can be found on [World of Waterfalls](http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/latin-america-angel-falls-how-to-get-there.html). They also explain in very detail how to get there.